# 18.04 local mirror missing some Translations-en

Tags: apt-mirror

built a local mirror for 18.04 with apt-mirror 0.5.4-1.  the mirror is on a usb drive, so sources.list uses file:.  apt-get update on a new install of 18.04.1 results in eight missing Translation-en files.

```
Err:9 file:/media/reposB/ubuntu1804/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main Translation-en
  File not found - /media/reposB/ubuntu1804/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/i18n/Translation-en (2: No such file or directory)


Err:21 file:/media/reposB/ubuntu1804/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main Translation-en
  File not found - /media/reposB/ubuntu1804/mirror/archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/i18n/Translation-en (2: No such file or directory)
```

the eight missing are:

```
./bionic-updates/restricted/i18n/
./bionic-updates/multiverse/i18n/
./bionic-updates/universe/i18n/
./bionic-updates/main/i18n/
./bionic/restricted/i18n/
./bionic/multiverse/i18n/
./bionic/universe/i18n/
./bionic/main/i18n/
```

in each one of those directories, the Index file contained the sha1 sum for the missing -en file.  so in each case, the Translation-en.gz file was uncompressed.  the result sha1 matched what was in the Index.  this step allowed the apt-get update to complete, with only a sandbox warning.  packages could then be installed from the local mirror.

i'm at a complete loss to determine why these eight translation files are missing since they are included in the Index file.  does anyone have a suggestion?

thanks.

Comment: I experienced the same problem with my USB local drive mirror. But, surprisingly since Jan 1st there is no answer !

Comment: i created a new 18.04 mirror on a new drive using 18.04.1 server.  i tested the mirror on a couple of 18.04.1 server virtual machines without any errors.  but when i try to use said mirror on a kubuntu 18.04.1 laptop, i'm now missing two dep11 icon-48x48.tar files.  i'm beginning to wonder if a mirror of 18.04 can even be done.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug with apt-mirror. I recently encountered this when testing Debian Buster upgrades. The script only grabs *.bz2 translation files, and since the Ubuntu repository only includes .gz and .xz files, they are ignored.

The Debian bug I filed is here, along with a trivial patch, which could easily be updated to include .gz files too:

https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=932379